# How to Remove/Hide Select Option from Dropdown menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Hi I am an nob in php and development and I have run into a problem that I have being trying to solve for two days.

I want to hide or remove an option from a drop-down menu that it calling its options from a database.
..................
An example of what I want to do is this.

Lets say my drop-down menu has three options that are coming back from the db e.g

- Mary
- John
- Peter

I want to hide John and only show Mary and Peter as select options, but without removing/deleting John from the db.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="id_address_delivery" class="address_select form-control" id="id_address_delivery">
    {foreach from=$addresses key=k item=address}

       <option value="{$address.id_address|intval}" selected selected{if $address.id_address == $cart->id_address_delivery} selected="selected"{/if}>{$address.alias|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</option>
    {/foreach}

</select>
```

Comment: why you want to hide John only why not others? is there any logic? what happen when 5-6 values or more comes as select option

Comment: Use an if statement within the foreach loop,  so an option tag is only created when a certain condition is met